# Error on LMest "Error in while ((lk - lko)/abs(lk) > tol & it < maxit) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm running an LM model using the LMest package available in R. The vector of the responses contains missing values but no missing values in the selected covariate "PROVINCE". Anyway, the rest covariates in the dataset do contain missing values.

My code is:

fmLatent <- lmestFormula(data = df, response = c("responseA", "responseB", "responseC", "responseD"), LatentInitial = c("PROVINCE"), LatentTransition = c("PROVINCE"))
mod <- lmest(responsesFormula = fmLatent$responsesFormula, latentFormula = fmLatent$latentFormula, index = c("ID", "Time"), data = df[,c(1:6,9)], k = 1:10, paramLatent = "multilogit", start = 0, out_se = TRUE)

## the dataset is filtered to having only 2 indices, 4 responses, and 1 covariate.

The error message follows:

Missing data in the dataset, treated as missing at random
------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
k     |    start    |     step    |     lk      |    lk-lko   | discrepancy |
------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
2 |           0 |           0 |         NaN |
Error in while ((lk - lko)/abs(lk) > tol & it < maxit) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I'm wondering how to address this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the start value to 1 instead of 0. I was having the same issue and this fixed it.